# Selenium: find input fieled element in Table

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Java and firefox for automation.
i have the following table:

```
   <table width="200" border="0">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="LEFT">User-ID: </td>
        <td>
         **<input name="username" size="25"/>**
       </td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
       <td align="LEFT">Password: </td>
       <td>
         **<input name="password" size="25" type="PASSWORD"/>**
      </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to reach the "Input name" and "Input password" in order to input my credentials. I have tried the following commands :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[7]/div[2]/form[2]/fieldset/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//table//tbody//tr//td[2]/input/@name")).sendKeys("XXXXXXX");
```

In both cases eclipse found nothing.

Can some one assist me with the correct xPath?

The error massage in Eclipse is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
```

Comment: What if you use `xpath` as `.//input[@name='password']`

Comment: What `error` ? Please add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below `code` using `xpath locator`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys("Username");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `name` attribute of `<input>` tag.

**Note:-** Instead of using `absolute xpath`, use `relative xpath`.

> OR

Try this below `code` using `cssSelector`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='username']")).sendKeys("Username");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");
```

Comment: Can you please show us your full tried code? because the same code is working for me, without showing any error.

Comment: Refer this question, this might will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608227/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-is-not-defi

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your HTML DOM this command will work for you:

You can use the "name" locator as:

`driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("your_username");`
`driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("your_password");`

OR

You can use the "xpath" locator as:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys("your_username");`
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("your_password");`

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Dev `xpath` and `name` are not an attribute, both are different locators.

Comment: @JainishKapadia Thanks, you are right, made correction.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why your answers are not working.
The error that i am getting is an actual Firefox issue.
Please refer to this link:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1357661

Many thanks to all that tried to help me.

Comment: So did you raise an issue with Selenium/GitHub or Gecko/GitHub ? What is the status now?

Comment: Please use the following link for more info:https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1357661. Meanwhile i am using IE for my porpoises.